# Getting all input fields of all forms pupeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

So I'm trying to scrape a page and get all forms on the page and in turn all input fields within those forms, I'm sure my logic is skewed so any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

My issue appears to be that form[0] is a JSHandle which I cannot enumerate as I need to get more than one piece of information from each input element.

I've tried running  `elements = await forms[i].$$eval("input", nodes => nodes.innerText)` as a text but this created an array with 15 empty elements

```
const forms = await page.$$("form")
if (forms.length == 0) {
    // DO something else
} else {
    for (let i = 0; i < forms.length; i++) {
        form = form[i]
        // GET ALL INPUT ELEMENTS HERE
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through them using `for (let form of forms)...` and getting form elements into an array of objects like in the code below.. p.s you can add what ever information you have in those forms by adding it into the loop, if you want to check if a form element exists or not you can use this format

ex. check if input type radio exists

```js
 let chk = await page.$['input[type=radio]']; 

if (!! chk) { 
  // exists
}  else {
  // doesn't exist.
}
```

Code :

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const html = `
    <form class="a">
        <input type="text" id="id1" name="some name" placeholder="some placeholder" value="A">
        <input type="text" id="id2" attr1="some name" attr2="some placeholder" value="B">
        <input type="text" attr3="some name" attr4="some placeholder" value="C">
        <button type="submit" class="submit1">Submit1</button>
    </form>
    <form class="b">
        <input type="text" id="id3" name="some name" placeholder="some placeholder" value="D">
        <input type="text" id="id4" attr1="some name" attr2="some placeholder" value="E">
        <input type="text" attr5="some name" attr6="some placeholder" value="F">
        <button type="submit" class="submit2">Submit2</button>
    </form>
`;

let browser;
(async () => {
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setContent(html);


    const forms = await page.$$("form");
    if (forms.lenght) { 
    // do something 
    } else {
        let formContent = [];
        for (let form of forms) {
            let inputs = await form.$$eval('input', el => el.map( x => x.getAttribute('value')));
            let button = await form.$eval('button', el => el.textContent);
            formContent.push({inputs : inputs, button : button});
        }
        console.log(formContent);
    }
    

})().catch(err => console.error(err)). finally(() => browser ?. close());
```